# Chrome: Javascript replaces `undefined` by `window` in "this" context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The actual version of Chrome apparently replaces `undefined` by `window` when being in context of `this`:

```
var n = function(a){ console.log(a,this); }; 
n.call(void(0),2);
n.call(undefined,2);
```

How do I avoid this?
In the logic of my app, `this` is supposed to be possible to be undefined, but it's also supposed to be possible to be `window`. How do I differenciate if chrome replaces it?

Comment: Use strict mode. Always use strict mode!

Comment: Works great, thanks a ton. Sorry for the duplicate, I didn't know this was "use strict" related.

Comment: No need to be sorry, it's not really a good duplicate - you couldn't have found it without knowing, it's not asking the same question. I just found the answer to be simple and needed a "duplicate" thread where you could find a longer explanation.